# Get the sum of first N primes javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum

I am trying to find the sum of the first N primes, below I have attached my code. I am struggling with the last part (getting the sum). So far I have defined what a prime number is and got the first N prime numbers

```js
function isPrime(number) {
  if (number <= 1) return false;
  if (number === 2) return true;
  else {
    for (let i = 2; i < number; i++) {
      if (number % i === 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
console.log(isPrime(6)); //false 

function getNprimes(n) {
  const arr = [];
  let i = 2

  while (arr.length < n) {
    if (isPrime(i)) {
      arr.push(i)
    }
    i++
  }
  return arr;
}
console.log(getNprimes(5)); //[2, 3, 5, 7, 11]

const sumOfNPrimes = (num) => {
  let sum = getNprimes(num);
  if (sum === 0) {
    sum = getNprimes(num + 1)
    return sum;
  }
}
console.log(sumOfNPrimes(4));
```

Comment: `if(sum === 0){` but `sum` is an array, no? (`getNprimes` returns an array)

Comment: Side-note but there are much better ways to check for prime numbers. For example, check `if( number % 2 === 0) return false;` first, then your loop can be `for( let i=3; i*i<=number; i+=2)` to cut down on a *lot* of checks that will never work.

Comment: And actually, since you're getting the first N primes, you can instead only check if the new number is divisible by any of the primes you've found so far. Even better!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The check `sum === 0` will always return `false` since `sum` is an array and you are using strict equality, which checks for types. You should be checking the `length` property instead, and using the `!=` operator (e.g, only execute the code if the length of the array is not `0`).

To calculate the sum of the resulting array, you can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
function isPrime(number) {
  if (number <= 1) return false;
  if (number === 2) return true;
  else {
    for (let i = 2; i < number; i++) {
      if (number % i === 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
console.log(isPrime(6)); //false 

function getNprimes(n) {
  const arr = [];
  let i = 2

  while (arr.length < n) {
    if (isPrime(i)) {
      arr.push(i)
    }
    i++
  }
  return arr;
}
console.log(getNprimes(5)); //[2, 3, 5, 7, 11]

const sumOfNPrimes = (num) => {
  let sum = getNprimes(num).reduce((a, b) => a + b);
  return sum
}
console.log(sumOfNPrimes(4));
```

Comment: You don't need to check for the length of the `sum` array, if the array is empty `.reduce()` will always return the initial value.

Comment: Also you can omit `0` in `.reduce` (it is minor but still ʘ‿ʘ)

Comment: Thank you. Is the 0 the same as sum=0

Comment: @KokoBear What do you mean?

Comment: does the 0 work as the initial value of sum, then the reduce would replace the sum?

Comment: @KokoBear `sum` can be shortened to `getNprimes(num).reduce((a, b) => a + b)`

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm you have implemented will run in O(N sqrt(N)) and it is finding the sum for every query.
So, if you want to reduce the time complexity of your code then you can implement sieve of erastosthenes which runs in O(N log (log N)) and store the values of sums of prime numbers in O(N) and then answer all queries in O(1) time complexity.
Below is the implementation of this idea in javascript:

```
let primes = [];
let primeSum = [2];
const N = 1000001;

function generatePrimes(){
    let isPrime = [];
    for(let i=1; i<N; i++) isPrime.push(true);
    for(let i=2; i<N; i++){
        if(!isPrime[i]) continue; // if number is not prime
        primes.push(i); // add prime number
        for(let j=2*i; j<N; j += i){
            isPrime[j] = false; // marking all multiples of                  current prime as non prime
        }
    }

// calculate prime sums from 0 index to ith index
    for(let i=1; i<primes.length; i++){
        if(i < 10) console.log(primes[i]);
        primeSum.push(Number(Number(primes[i])+Number(primeSum[i-    1])));
    }
}

generatePrimes();

// answer query in O(1) for n = 10:
const n = 3;
console.log(primeSum[n-1]);
```

you can also answer l to r range query prime sums with this code

ps: sorry for bad english